# Why textBox in WinForms cant display double?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, types, windows-forms-designer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace P2_7_24_2016_ED_app
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int win;
        int loss;
        int winCounter;
        int lossCounter;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonWin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBoxWin.Text = "";
            ++win;
            ++winCounter;
            this.textBoxWin.Text = win.ToString();
        }

        private void buttonLoss_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBoxLoss.Text = "";
            ++loss;
            ++lossCounter;
            this.textBoxLoss.Text = loss.ToString();
        }

        private void buttonRate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            double result = winCounter / (winCounter + lossCounter);
            textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in windows form application, its short so i'm not going to explain everything.
Problem is that in the end `textBox1.Text = result.ToString();`
is showing "0", but it should be some numbers. When the win winCounter is like 1, and lossCounter is 1 it should insert 1/(1+1) = 0.5 but it says "0". I tried everything i knew so please give me a tip.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows Forms. You'd see the exact same result in a console app of about 5 lines. Hint: `winCounter` and `lossCounter` are both integers. 1/(1+1) = 0 when performed with integer arithmetic.

Comment: Cast dividend to double.

Comment: i tried saving it in double Result, but it still shows "0"

Comment: You need to cast one of the parts of the equation to a floating point type *before* assigning it or converting to a string.

Comment: i edited the code added Double Result.  its still shows "0"

Comment: @FrostyBacon you will need to use it **within** your equation. Or take the doniminator **alone** and cast it to double then continue. See the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is integer arithmetic:

```
(winCounter/(winCounter+lossCounter))
```

The result is not going to be what you expect.

Cast either `winCounter` or `(winCounter+lossCounter)` to a floating point type (float, double or decimal depending on the speed/accuracy you need) before doing the division:

```
 (winCounter/(decimal)(winCounter+lossCounter))
```

or

```
 ((double)winCounter/(winCounter+lossCounter))
```

and you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: @RicGaudet  - yes, either works. You just have to cast one side to tell the compiler that this is floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments, you will need to `cast` your result. This should work:

```
textBox1.Text = (winCounter/(double)(winCounter+lossCounter)).ToString();
```

Comment: Casting the result will still result in integer arithmetic. You need to cast *before* doing the division.